# Is there a URL to ask a pre-tagged question?

Tags: support, tags, best-practice

I'd like to say, on another web site, *please ask a question on AskUbuntu tagged `foo`*, and make that a link to the 'ask' form here with the tags already populated, so that it's more likely the right people will see it quickly.  Is there any way to make such a URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well who knew? **There is!**

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask?tags=tag,tags2
```

You can also suggest the initial title with `title=something` (join the two with an `&`)

Example from developer.ubuntu.com (See the ask a question link):

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/